# Make objects bounce from edge of the screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make objects bounce from the edges of the screen and I'm struggling to do it on Swift.

This is what I'm trying now:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // bounce of edges
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: do you have a specific question? or just asking for code?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to know how do you make objects bounce from the edge of the screen. I don't need the specific code, if somebody can explain how to create a game map I can figure out how to give it the same size as the screen. The problem is that most examples and documentation covers, endless runners and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add `self.size = view.bounds.size`: inside didMoveToView. This gives the Scene the same size as the viewport.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.size = view.bounds.size
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to adjust my frame a little to get this to work.

`let frame = CGRectMake(255, 0, 515, self.frame.size.height)
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)`

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. I probably have to adjust the frame as you mentioned though but I don't know how to do it. Also would this work regardless screen size?

Comment: Hmm.. can this be fixed by changing the ViewController to the correct size and orientation you are using? For example: iphone 4inch and portrait orientation.

Comment: Clicking on the storyboard -> the ViewController -> Attributes Inspector -> Simulated Metrics. Seems to allow you to change the size of your frame.